# Why do openSea fetching data from IPFS all of a sudden?

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, ipfs, nft

This the validation json I got for my nft toke 34

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "valid": true,
    "token_uri": "https://opensea.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/QmSEPUYN23YHfcsxgHHFodDTTdGuu8yhShuXpyJLe7RE6t/34.json",
    "errors": []
}
```

This is for token 35

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: OPTIONS, GET
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "valid": false,
    "token_uri": null,
    "errors": [
        "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'list'"
    ]
}
```

What possibly could go wrong that it stopped working all of a sudden.

[My IPFS](https://opensea.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/QmSEPUYN23YHfcsxgHHFodDTTdGuu8yhShuXpyJLe7RE6t) -

[OpenSea Collection](https://opensea.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/QmSEPUYN23YHfcsxgHHFodDTTdGuu8yhShuXpyJLe7RE6t)

Comment: Got exactly the same problem, metadata works fine on  https://rinkeby.looksrare.org/

Comment: Sorry, can you elaborate what I need to do. I actually want to deploy on mainnet. I am confused as is it a problem from my end ?why is it happening? @zhangzhimin

Comment: Having the same problem for last 4 days. It drives me crazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a problem, that started today. On the discord channel, multiple people have the same problem. My guess, it is an error from the side of opensea

Comment: I have the same issue, Rarible and LooksRare works normally

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).